# No Such Column while compiling DELETE FROM table

Tags: sqlite

I am getting an error like "No Such Column while compiling DELETE FROM table".
please help

```
public String getData() {


    String[] columns = new String []{KEY_ROWID, KEY_HEADER, KEY_QUOTE_VALUE};


    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iHeader = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HEADER);
    int iQuote_value = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUOTE_VALUE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iRow)+ "@" +c.getString(iHeader)+ ":" +c.getString(iQuote_value)+ ":";
    }

    return result;

}

public void deleteEntry(String Deldata1) throws SQLException {
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_HEADER + "=" + Deldata1 , null);

}
```

}

please help me

Comment: what you need ? Where is your delete query.

Answer (score 0):

The Deldata1 variable is probably not initialized to a quoted string.

Print the value of KEY_HEADER and Deldata1 in the deleteEntry function before the delete call.

Atleast one should be the name of a table in the database. The other can be a table name or a quoted string.